# Stackpanel: Black background on wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, stackpanel

I have one problem - my stackpanel is vey big and it breaks(background color is changed to black).. What should i do to improve it?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF2D2D2D" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
    ..
    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer Name="viewer" Grid.Row="1" >
        <StackPanel Name="ContentGrid" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Margin="0, 0,0,80" Background="White"  Width="452">

            <Image Name="ImageImage"  Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBlock  Name="DateText" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBlock Name="TitleText"  TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Margin="10,0"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"  Margin="10,15,10,2" Name="DescroptionText"  FontSize="23" Foreground="#FF494949" FontFamily="Portable User Interface"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"  Margin="10,0,10,2" Name="DescroptionText2"  FontSize="23" Foreground="#FF494949"/>
            <ListBox SelectionChanged="GridImages_SelectionChanged"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Name="GridImages" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AttachmentsItemTemlate}" Grid.RowSpan="2" FontFamily="Portable User Interface" >
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  ItemWidth="150" ItemHeight="150"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limitation of 2048px in Windows Phone UIElements.

You should try to break your different elements into smaller elements (for example: you could put several stackpanels inside the first one).

In TextBox elements there is a workaround explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx?Redirected=true).

Comment: Thanks. Can you attach small example with ScrollableTextBlock please? I have tried, but it wasn't ok..

Comment: Something like this?

`<ScrollViewer Margin="12,0,12,0">
<StackPanel>
<TextBlock Text="Example1" FontSize="150" />
<TextBlock Text="Example2" FontSize="150" />
</StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>`

Comment: No, this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx?Redirected=true I did as it is written there, but it doesn't work

Comment: It's not the first code snippet of the page. You have to do what is on the rest of the page. If it doesn't work, there is not much I can help you with, since I'm not able to look at your code. That code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, but first you need to add windows toolkit library.

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

<toolkit:PhoneTextBox 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Name="txtString" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
            MaxHeight="200"
            PlaceholderText="Add text"
            Padding="5"
            Width="370"
            FontFamily="Open Sans Light"
            FontSize="22"
            Height="Auto" ///Use Auto or provide height value
            Margin="10" 
      />
```

This code is used for Scrolling as well work for Auto Growing Textbox. If you don't want Auto Growing Textbox then provide height instead of **Auto** in Height attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Best this is to make the Main Window to white background and Make your stackpanel as transparent background instead of giving any color to it. It works great as I have tested it.